# Make slds calendar form float above modal

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I'm using the slds modal and have a calendar form inside of it. When clicked that calendar stay hidden and you need to scroll to see it. I'd like it to pop above the modal. I'd also like the avoid custom css and stick to what slds offers. Is there something in slds that will solve my problem?

[image]

```
    <div id="mass-update-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-modal__close">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="toggleModal('#mass-update-modal')">
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Turning off Territory Management</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <p>Select the next day for the Mass Update of Territory Management to run.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">                      
                <form class="slds-form--inline slds-float--left" style="">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input_date">Next Update:</label>
                        <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-input__icon slds-icon-text-default">
                                    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#event')}"></use>
                                </svg>
                                <apex:inputText styleClass="slds-input datepicker" value="{!LeadTerrSetup.Next_Mass_Update_Date_Lead__c}"/>
                            </div>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </form>   
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="">Effective Immediately</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="">Schedule</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=""></div>
```

Comment: This is a problem in SLDS, it even happens for drop-down. Add z-index:9999 to that div.

Comment: The div containing the form? If that is the case, it's not working.

Comment: The div which wraps the calendar.